# web.py with FastCGI and lighttpd in windows

Tags: python, windows, fastcgi, lighttpd, web.py

I'm trying to make my web.py app in python 2.7 to production level as described in this [document](http://webpy.org/install) in a **windows** environment. So I referred the

> Production --> LightTPD --> .. with FastCGI

section in the above page. 
First installed flup and then added

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to my Code.py

Then I downloaded lighttpd from [here](http://lighttpd.dtech.hu/) and extracted LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL.zip .

Next I edited lighttpd.conf as mentioned in the document. Since I use Windows I used full paths to make it work as follows.

```
server.modules = ("mod_fastcgi", "mod_rewrite")
server.document-root = "C:\Python27\New folder\LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL\LightTPD\htdocs\Engine" 
fastcgi.server = ( "\Code.py" =>     
 (( "socket" => "C:\Python27\New folder\LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL\LightTPD\htdocs\Engine\tmp\fastcgi.socket",
    "bin-path" => "C:\Python27\New folder\LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL\LightTPD\htdocs\Engine\Code.py",
    "max-procs" => 1
 ))
 )
url.rewrite-once = (
   "^/favicon.ico$" => "/static/favicon.ico",
   "^/static/(.*)$" => "/static/$1",
   "^/(.*)$" => "/Code.py/$1"
 )
```

This is my Code.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
__author__ = 'Marlon'
import web
import json
import time

urls = (
    '/foo(.*)', 'Foo'
)
class Foo(web.storage):

    def GET(self,r):
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        result = time.sleep(30)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

When I try to run LightTPD.exe from command prompt it gives me this error.

```
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (server.c.645) trying to read configuration (test mode)
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (log.c.194) server started
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1102) the fastcgi-backend C:\Python27\New folder\LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL\LightTPD\htdoc\Engine\Code.py failed to start:
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1106) child exited with status 2 C:\Python27\New folder\LightTPD-1.4.39-1-IPv6-Win32-SSL\LightTPD\htdoc\Engine\Code.py
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1109) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.\nIf this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1395) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
2016-07-20 00:02:23: (server.c.1057) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down
```

Do I need to install anything  related to FastCGI? I have came across [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd) which asks to install [this](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=fcgi) but that's not for windows. Do I need to separately install this for windows if so where can I get it? Is it the problem that the above error comes?

Answer (score 0):

Please try lighttpd 1.4.40, released earlier this week.  It works much better on Windows than previous versions.  You'll need a cygwin environment to build it from source, but then the executable can run outside the cygwin environment.

Comment: At least with lighttpd 1.4.40, I'd recommend using unix-style paths, not Windows paths with backslashes.  For access to paths outside cygwin environment, try "/cygdrive/c/Python27/New folder/..."

Comment: You probably want to test your script standalone to find out why lighttpd is unable to start it.  You might be missing Python modules that your script needs you to install.

FYI: lighttpd 1.4.42 supports uwsgi protocol
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSCGI

See also:
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI